# Repurposing old FPGAs

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, altcoin, fpga

So, I have a couple of BTC mining FPGAs lying around from the earlier days when they were worth running (specifically a BPMC Red Fury and an ASICMiner Block Erupter). I'm wondering if these can be used to mine any other cryptocurrencies that might be a little more profitable these days. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are ASIC miners, not FPGA.

They can mine BTC and clones, but nothing else.